# Swift: If Let with Multiple Cell Classes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView with 2 prototype cells: CourseCell and BllCell. These cells contain a UISlider and an IBAction is in place on the main ViewController.

After the slider has finished moving the following action is triggered:

```
@IBAction func sliderFinishedMoving(_ sender: Any) {
    if let slider = sender as? gradeSlider {
        if let superview = slider.superview {

            if let cell = superview.superview as? CourseCell {

                let selectedSemester = cell.activeSemester

                let selectedIndexPath = courseTable.indexPath(for: cell)!
                let selectedCourse = courseTypes[selectedIndexPath.section].courses[selectedIndexPath.row]

                if selectedCourse.examType == "" && selectedCourse.examCourse == true {
                    print("please select the exam type before entering grades")
                    slider.value = 0.0
                    cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.origin.x = slider.thumbCenterX - (cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.width/2)
                    cell.gradeSliderLabel.text = "0"
                    return
                }

                print(selectedIndexPath.section, selectedIndexPath.row)

                slider.value = round(slider.value)
                cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.origin.x = slider.thumbCenterX - (cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.width/2)

                switch(selectedSemester) {
                case 1:
                    selectedCourse.semester1Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 2:
                    selectedCourse.semester2Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 3:
                    selectedCourse.semester3Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 4:
                    selectedCourse.semester4Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 5:
                    selectedCourse.examGrade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 6:
                    selectedCourse.oralGrade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }

                courseTable.reloadData()
            }

            if let cell = superview.superview as? BllCell {

                let selectedSemester = cell.activeSemester

                let selectedIndexPath = courseTable.indexPath(for: cell)!
                let selectedCourse = courseTypes[selectedIndexPath.section].courses[selectedIndexPath.row]

                if selectedCourse.examType == "" && selectedCourse.examCourse == true {
                    print("please select the exam type before entering grades")
                    slider.value = 0.0
                    cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.origin.x = slider.thumbCenterX - (cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.width/2)
                    cell.gradeSliderLabel.text = "0"
                    return
                }

                print(selectedIndexPath.section, selectedIndexPath.row)

                slider.value = round(slider.value)
                cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.origin.x = slider.thumbCenterX - (cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.width/2)

                switch(selectedSemester) {
                case 1:
                    selectedCourse.semester1Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 2:
                    selectedCourse.semester2Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 3:
                    selectedCourse.semester3Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 4:
                    selectedCourse.semester4Grade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 5:
                    selectedCourse.examGrade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                case 6:
                    selectedCourse.oralGrade = Int(slider.value)
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }

                courseTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is duplicate code. Is it possible to fire if let cell ... with both CourseCell and BllCell in order to access the cell.activeSemester variable in both without having to duplicate the function?

Comment: Apart from the spaghetti code you've shared with us, this is really the most terrible way of getting cell from its subsub view. You should redesign your logic and consider using [delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Comment: Why are you getting the cell? Access your data model, not the view.

Comment: ... and except the two `default` `break`s you can omit all other `break` statements. They are not needed in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a common parent for both `BllCell` `CourseCell` if you are performing the same instruction.

Comment: That may or may not be useful. The real answer is to avoid accessing the cell at all in the code. There's no reason the code in the question should even be trying to access any cell.

Comment: I hope you understand this :)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with this code but the immediate answer to your specific question is to use a protocol:

```
protocol GradeSliderCell: class {
    var activeSemester: Int { get }
    var gradeSliderLabel: UILabel! { get }
}
```

Both `CourseCell` and `BllCell` should conform to this protocol.

That cuts the duplicated code in half:

```
@IBAction func sliderFinishedMoving(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let slider = sender as? gradeSlider else { return }
    guard let superview = slider.superview else { return }

    if let cell = superview.superview as? GradeSliderCell {

        let selectedSemester = cell.activeSemester

        let selectedIndexPath = courseTable.indexPath(for: cell as! UITableViewCell)!
        let selectedCourse = courseTypes[selectedIndexPath.section].courses[selectedIndexPath.row]

        if selectedCourse.examType == "" && selectedCourse.examCourse == true {
            print("please select the exam type before entering grades")
            slider.value = 0.0
            cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.origin.x = slider.thumbCenterX - (cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.width/2)
            cell.gradeSliderLabel.text = "0"
            return
        }

        print(selectedIndexPath.section, selectedIndexPath.row)

        slider.value = round(slider.value)
        cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.origin.x = slider.thumbCenterX - (cell.gradeSliderLabel.frame.width/2)

        switch(selectedSemester) {
        case 1:
            selectedCourse.semester1Grade = Int(slider.value)
        case 2:
            selectedCourse.semester2Grade = Int(slider.value)
        case 3:
            selectedCourse.semester3Grade = Int(slider.value)
        case 4:
            selectedCourse.semester4Grade = Int(slider.value)
        case 5:
            selectedCourse.examGrade = Int(slider.value)
        case 6:
            selectedCourse.oralGrade = Int(slider.value)
        default:
            break
        }

        courseTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```